# Calculate the height of an asp:TextBox (textarea) without linebreaks

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, textarea, height

I have an asp:TextBox (which renders as an textarea) and I need to calculate the height of that TextBox to fit the content for printing. I calculate the height of the textarea with this code:

```cs
// get the number of lines 
int numberOflines = txtText.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\n' }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
    
//calculate the target hight of the textBox
txtText.Rows = numberOflines;
txtText.Style.Add("height", TextBoxHeight.calculate(11, 8, numberOflines, 9999999) 
    + "px;");
```

The code works fine - as long there is a line break for every line, but if this is not the case the resulting height is to small. How can I get the correct height independend of line breaks?

I have tried multiple ways with javascript but they require user actions like onkeyup (in my case users can change the text but they shouldn't have to) or they also do some calculations based on the number of linebreaks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reliable method which works after some sort of user interaction like onkeyup why not just trigger that first manually before using the reliable method?

```
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $("button").click( function(){
       $("#txt").trigger("onkeyup");  // manually invoke keyup event
     });
   });

  <button>Manual trigger keyup</button>
  <input type="text" onkeyup="alert('up');" id="txt" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The calclulation of the height has to work without user input. User input should be possible but not necessary.

Comment: The user doesn't actually have to do any real input with the above method. You simulate user input with the .trigger() line, then use whatever method would have worked should they have actually done some input.