# Can't save innerText / innerHTML of an editable div in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I try to save the changed text of an editable div. I put some text on page load into the div and change it in the browser, but I can't save the changes because the innerHTML content doesn't change.

This is my aspx file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div contenteditable="true" runat="server" id="txtText" ></div>
      <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Speichern" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code behind file:

```
public partial class editWordModule : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            txtText.InnerHTML = "This is the unmodified text";
        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string test = txtText.InnerHtml;
            //still shows "This is the unmodified text" while it was changed before in the div

        }
    }
}
```

So how do I save the edited innerHTML of the div?

Comment: I don't believe the div content is posted back - and the state of divs are not saved (no view state). So you would be a gazillion times better to just drop in a plane jane asp.net text box.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal : 'plain' (as in, plain and simple). ; )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using a div because textboxes don't fit automatically to the content what a div does. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67581061/calculate-the-height-of-an-asptextbox-textarea-without-linebreaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a little trick with JavaScript.
When the button is clicked, get the innerHTML of DIV and put into a asp:HiddenField

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
       <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function ChangeDiv() {
            var div = document.getElementById("txtText");
            var hdn = document.getElementById("hdnText");
            hdn.value = div.innerHTML;
        }
        </script>

        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div contenteditable="true" id="txtText"></div>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnText" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Speichern" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="ChangeDiv()" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in your code behind  read the hidden field.

```
string hdn = hdnText.Value
```

Comment: Thank you Eduardo, I will try this next week :-)